# Input in table is causing the table width to change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

So here I have a table in which I am able to add, delete and edit new data for the respective columns.

```
    <table class="table table-borderless table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr class="head">
                <th>Set</th>
                <th>Reps</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="" id="body">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                    <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                    <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                    <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                    <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button id="add_button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary add-new"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Set</button>
```

Currently, the table is set as `table-responsive` which means the width is adjusted to the length of column. Before adding a new set, I have the table like so:

[Before Adding New Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whb07.png)

After pressing the button to add a new set, the style change to this:

[After Adding New Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wue0W.png)

As you can see, the table width is stretched even though I have set it to be `table-responsive`. Below is my Script.

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
var actions = $("table td:last-child").html();

// Append table with add row form on add new button click
$(".add-new").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
    var row = '<tr>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control w-25" name="name" id="name"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control w-25" name="department" id="department"></td>' +
        '<td>' + actions + '</td>' +
    '</tr>';
    $("table").append(row);
    $("table tbody tr").eq(index + 1).find(".add, .edit").toggle();
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});

// Add row on add button click
$(document).on("click", ".add", function(){
    var empty = false;
    var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="text"]');
    input.each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()){
            $(this).addClass("error");
            empty = true;
        } else{
            $(this).removeClass("error");
        }
    });
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".error").first().focus();
    if(!empty){
        input.each(function(){
            $(this).parent("td").html($(this).val());
        });
        $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
        $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});

// Edit row on edit button click
$(document).on("click", ".edit", function(){
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").each(function(){
        $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control w-2" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
    });
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
    $(".add-new").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});

// Delete row on delete button click
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function(){
    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
    $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

My question is how can I make it so that the width stays the same without it changing when trying to add or edit the existing data?

Working Snippet Here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap Table with Add and Delete Row Feature</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round|Open+Sans">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        color: #404E67;
        background: #F5F7FA;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }
 .table-wrapper {
  width: 580px;
  margin: 30px auto;
        background: transparent;
        padding: 20px;
        border-style: solid;

    height: 500px;
    }
    .table-title {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        margin: 0 0 10px;
    }
    .table-title h2 {
        margin: 6px 0 0;
        font-size: 22px;
    }



    table.table {
      margin-left: ;
    }

    table.table tr th, table.table tr td {
        border-color: #e9e9e9;
    }
    table.table th i {
        font-size: 13px;
        margin: 0 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    table.table th:last-child {
        width: 100px;
    }
    table.table td a {
  cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 5px;
  min-width: 24px;
    }
 table.table td a.add {
        color: #27C46B;
    }
    table.table td a.edit {
        color: #FFC107;
    }
    table.table td a.delete {
        color: #E34724;
    }
    table.table td i {
        font-size: 19px;
    }
 table.table td a.add i {
        font-size: 24px;
     margin-right: -1px;
        position: relative;
        top: 3px;
    }
    table.table .form-control {
        height: 32px;
        line-height: 32px;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }
 table.table .form-control.error {
  border-color: #f50000;
 }
 table.table td .add {
  display: none;
 }
  table th{
    width: auto !important;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  td{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .head{
    background-color:#4D4F5C;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  }

  #body{
    background-color:#4D4F5C;
  }

  #add_button{

  }

  h4{
    text-align: center;
  }



</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
 var actions = $("table td:last-child").html();

 // Append table with add row form on add new button click
    $(".add-new").click(function(){
  $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
  var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
        var row = '<tr>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control w-25" name="name" id="name"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control w-25" name="department" id="department"></td>' +
            '<td>' + actions + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
     $("table").append(row);
  $("table tbody tr").eq(index + 1).find(".add, .edit").toggle();
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });

 // Add row on add button click
 $(document).on("click", ".add", function(){
  var empty = false;
  var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="text"]');
        input.each(function(){
   if(!$(this).val()){
    $(this).addClass("error");
    empty = true;
   } else{
                $(this).removeClass("error");
            }
  });
  $(this).parents("tr").find(".error").first().focus();
  if(!empty){
   input.each(function(){
    $(this).parent("td").html($(this).val());
   });
   $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
   $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
    });

 // Edit row on edit button click
 $(document).on("click", ".edit", function(){
        $(this).parents("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").each(function(){
   $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control w-2" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
  });
  $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
  $(".add-new").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });

 // Delete row on delete button click
 $(document).on("click", ".delete", function(){
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
  $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
            <div class="table-title">
                <h4>AB ROLL OUTS</h4>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-borderless table-responsive">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="head">
                        <th>Set</th>
                        <th>Reps</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="" id="body">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>
       <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>
       <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>



                <button id="add_button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary add-new"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Set</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the cells as `position: relative` and then the inputs withing it as `position: absolute` and their width can then be adjusted accordingly.

I've made the width of inputs to be width of cell (excluding the paddings).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap Table with Add and Delete Row Feature</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round|Open+Sans">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        color: #404E67;
        background: #F5F7FA;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }
 .table-wrapper {
  width: 580px;
  margin: 30px auto;
        background: transparent;
        padding: 20px;
        border-style: solid;

    height: 500px;
    }
    .table-title {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        margin: 0 0 10px;
    }
    .table-title h2 {
        margin: 6px 0 0;
        font-size: 22px;
    }



    table.table {
      margin-left: ;
    }

    table.table tr th, table.table tr td {
        border-color: #e9e9e9;
        position: relative;
    }
    table.table th i {
        font-size: 13px;
        margin: 0 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    table.table th:last-child {
        width: 100px;
    }
    table.table td a {
  cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 5px;
  min-width: 24px;
    }
 table.table td a.add {
        color: #27C46B;
    }
    table.table td a.edit {
        color: #FFC107;
    }
    table.table td a.delete {
        color: #E34724;
    }
    table.table td i {
        font-size: 19px;
    }
 table.table td a.add i {
        font-size: 24px;
     margin-right: -1px;
        position: relative;
        top: 3px;
    }
    table.table .form-control {
        height: 32px;
        line-height: 32px;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-radius: 2px;
        position: absolute;
        width: calc(100% - 24px);   
        padding: 0px;
    }
 table.table .form-control.error {
  border-color: #f50000;
 }
 table.table td .add {
  display: none;
 }
  table th{
    width: auto !important;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  td{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .head{
    background-color:#4D4F5C;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  }

  #body{
    background-color:#4D4F5C;
  }

  #add_button{

  }

  h4{
    text-align: center;
  }



</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
 var actions = $("table td:last-child").html();

 // Append table with add row form on add new button click
    $(".add-new").click(function(){
  $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
  var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
        var row = '<tr>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control w-25" name="name" id="name"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control w-25" name="department" id="department"></td>' +
            '<td>' + actions + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
     $("table").append(row);
  $("table tbody tr").eq(index + 1).find(".add, .edit").toggle();
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });

 // Add row on add button click
 $(document).on("click", ".add", function(){
  var empty = false;
  var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="text"]');
        input.each(function(){
   if(!$(this).val()){
    $(this).addClass("error");
    empty = true;
   } else{
                $(this).removeClass("error");
            }
  });
  $(this).parents("tr").find(".error").first().focus();
  if(!empty){
   input.each(function(){
    $(this).parent("td").html($(this).val());
   });
   $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
   $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
    });

 // Edit row on edit button click
 $(document).on("click", ".edit", function(){
        $(this).parents("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").each(function(){
   $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control w-2" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
  });
  $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
  $(".add-new").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });

 // Delete row on delete button click
 $(document).on("click", ".delete", function(){
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
  $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
            <div class="table-title">
                <h4>AB ROLL OUTS</h4>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-borderless table-responsive">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="head">
                        <th>Set</th>
                        <th>Reps</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="" id="body">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>
       <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>
       <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>



                <button id="add_button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary add-new"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Set</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It possible to move the input field to the middle of column header? Like more in the middle